# How to check user input for repeating text

Tags: php, user-input, validation, repeat

When there is a character amount requirement. Some users may fill in the remaining quota with garbage text that repeats. I want to set the amount of repeats to allow.

Comment: I hate character amount requirements.. your users do write "that" amount of text for some reason maybe? Any pseudo check you'll create will still be easy to dodge and annoy your (already frustrated) users a little bit more

Answer (score 1):

```
    $input = "this is a test to see if there are repeats in this sentence blah blah blah as these three here";


    if(check_input($input, 3) === false)
        var_dump("No repeat found");
    else
        var_dump("Repeat found");


    function check_input($input, $maximum_repeats){
        $repeat_found = false;

        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($input) && $repeat_found == false; $i++){

            for($k = 0; $k < strlen($input) && $repeat_found == false; $k++){
                $test = substr($input, $i, $k);

                if(strlen($test) > 0){
                    if(find_repeat($test, $input, $maximum_repeats) === true){
                        $repeat_found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $repeat_found;
    }

    function find_repeat($target, $input, $amount){
        $needle = "";

        for($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++)
            $needle .= $target;

        return strpos($input, $needle) !== false;
    }
```

This function would ring true for "blah blah blah" and other examples such as

> ok...